# Android and J2ME

Tags: android, java-me

Can anyone please clear my doubt regarding the query that does Android Programming has anything to do with the J2ME?

Does Android Development comes under J2ME Platform as J2ME is used basically for the Mobile Applications and Android is also the same one.

Please let me know if anybody is knowing it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android has nothing to do with J2ME beyond using the core Java language. In fact, the standard library is more reminiscent of Java SE.

Answer (score 1):

Like Yann mentioned , j2me is not Android and vice versa, however they use the same language with different VMS. Google basically created their own JVM called DAVLIk which got Sun to sue Google because google used their technology without their approval.

There are however some J2ME to Android wrappers. LWUIT currently has such a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

in both same language will used which is JAVA.

but j2me is made for small devices which is run on kJVM .,

Android is basically made for smart devices.,

using j2me we can developed Third party app .,but Android is the native app which is fully supported by Android OS.

Answer (score 0):

Also you may want to look at MicroEmulator http://microemu.blogspot.ru/2009/08/converting-javame-applications-to.html, it provides J2ME CLDC/MIDP wrappers for Java SE and Android, so basically you can write a midlet and pack it with MicroEmu to run on Android. But it will limit your app to J2ME UI which is quite weak, no comparison with Android. CodenameOne (former LWUIT mentioned in other answer) is a best choice for a cross-platform solution if you need to cover J2ME, Blackberry, Android, iOS and Windows Phone. But if you do not need to support J2ME and Blackberry, there are other solutions too (Xamarin, Marmelade, PhoneGap)