# Android and java Association

Tags: java, android

Can anybody please tell me that how closely Android Application Development is associated with Java. That is, is it possible for a person working in Android Development to work on Core Java or J2EE or J2SE ever?

Let me make my question a bit more clear: " As Android is based on Java, but does it depends on Java so well that a person from the Android development side can work in Core Java or J2EE or in J2SE.?

Seeking really to know this now.

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243497/android-and-j2me

Comment: @ognian - The question you referred to was regarding JavaME, which is considerably different than JavaSE, so I don't think it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java EE is just a group of specifications, basically, I believe 13 or so, but, if you do Android development you will need to know Java, so, depending on how much knowledge you expect to transfer what you do in Android will help you with Java SE, but, for Java EE that is a matter of learning the various technologies that make up that stack.

Java is the language that is used to write Android applications, so it does depend on it.

But, some of the ways that you approach Android applications will be different than in most Java frameworks or environments. For example, their concept of an `Activity` is something that I haven't seen, as they have implemented it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do Android development you will know the java language (some of it, anyway), but none of the frameworks necessary to work in those other environments.

For instance, Java EE is really a jungle of specifications and competing frameworks and a good Java EE developer knows what's out there and can choose between the different parts. I'm slightly exaggerating the "jungle" part for dramatic effect, it's not all that bad when you know the landscape, but you have to know it. If joining an existing project, you could get up to speed fairly quickly with basic usage of all the different parts, but you won't be able to just jump in and start coding.

So, "maybe".

Answer (score 0):

To your question:

> is it possible for a person working in
>   Android Development to work on Core
>   Java or J2EE or J2SE ever?

If you mean without learning JavaSE or JavaEE: no, you can't unless you want to work on trivial Hello World! programs. Since Android was introduced way after Java SE and EE, the general case is the opposite - Java programmers are learning Android to write for it. But if you started your programming on Android, you still need to learn what is Java SE and EE, and how to program for it.