# j2me to android

Tags: android, java-me

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [moving to android from j2me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64745/moving-to-android-from-j2me)

shall we reuse the j2me source code for android application.i have the j2me source code.is this easy to convert the j2me code to android code

Answer (score 0):

You can fed your J2ME code and get Android apk.

Refer this URL:

http://www.netmite.com/android/srv/2.0/getapk.php

Answer (score 0):

See this for an answer: [Android and J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243497/android-and-j2me)

There also exists automatic conversion service - http://upontek.com/J2MEtoAndroidServices.php you may want to try